# Azure Blob Storage REST API signature

Tags: azure, azure-storage, restful-authentication

I have been working on a proof of concept and looking to test against the Azure Storage REST API. However, I cannot authenticate. I have tried all day with reading and tweaking and rewriting and it still does not work. I have been through the documentation step by step.

I am hoping to find someone who has managed this. Lots of hard coded bits, it is just to get it working. I keep getting this error back in response

> The MAC signature found in the HTTP request '' is not the same as any computed signature

Can anyone see what is maybe staring me in the face? It's driving me mad.

```
    var requestDateString = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    var StorageAccountName = "<account removed>";
    var StorageKey = "<key removed>";

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var stringToSign = new List<string>(){
        "GET"                                                                                               /*HTTP Verb*/  
        ,""                                                                                                 /*Content-Encoding*/  
        ,""                                                                                                 /*Content-Language*/  
        ,""                                                                                            /*Content-Length (include value when zero)*/  
        ,""                                                                                                 /*Content-MD5*/  
        ,""                                                                                                 /*Content-Type*/  
        ,""                                                                                                 /*Date*/  
        ,""                                                                                                 /*If-Modified-Since */  
        ,""                                                                                                 /*If-Match*/  
        ,""                                                                                                 /*If-None-Match*/  
        ,""                                                                                                 /*If-Unmodified-Since*/  
        ,""                                                                                                 /*Range*/  
        ,$"x-ms-date:{requestDateString}\nx-ms-version:2015-02-21"                                          /*CanonicalizedHeaders*/
        ,$"/{StorageAccountName}/ " + _containerName + "\ncomp:metadata\nrestype:container\ntimeout:20"     /*CanonicalizedResource*/
        };


        string signature;
        using (var hmac = new HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String(StorageKey)))
        {
            var compiledStringToSign = (string.Join("\n", stringToSign));
            byte[] dataToHmac = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(compiledStringToSign);
            signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(dataToHmac));
        }

        //Send Request
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-date", requestDateString);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-version", " 2015-02-21");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"SharedKey {StorageAccountName}:" + signature);

        var response = client.SendAsync(request);
```

//edit
The Request URL is https://account.blob.core.windows.net/testcontainer/blobtest/blob1234

The error is quite specific about failing authentication so I think the error must be in the signature, i really can't see it though. I checked all the outputs with fiddler to ensure they matched

Comment: May I ask why you do not use Azure Storage SDK for C#?

Comment: I once implemented this in Python when there was no SDK. AFAIK the C# SDK is open source at GitHub and you can review the code - two years ago I found the implementation very readable

Comment: Can you share the request URL as well?

Comment: I have it working with the SDK already but want to see if I can get better speeds with the REST API. The SDK has a 'warm up' on first request which is 500-1000ms. If you ran a test app and downloaded 10 images individually, first is 500ms and rest are 50ms. I logged it with MS but they said its SDK caching and by design. For a web app, every request is like the first run so it can be a bit slow. Hoping using REST API will bypass that.

Comment: for documentation purposes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authentication-for-the-azure-storage-services

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the blob content, please have a try to use the following demo code, it works correctly on my side.

```
var blobStorageAccount = "account name";
var storageKey = "account key";
var containerName = "container name";
var requestMethod = "GET";
var blobName = "blob name"; // in your case:blobtest/blob1234
var dt = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var msVersion = "2015-02-21";
var clientRequestId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
var canHeaders = $"x-ms-client-request-id:{clientRequestId}\nx-ms-date:{dt}\nx-ms-version:{msVersion}";
var canResource = $"/{blobStorageAccount}/{containerName}/{blobName}"; //not the CanonicalizedResource : /myaccount/mycontainer\ncomp:metadata\nrestype:container\ntimeout:20
var signStr = $"{requestMethod}\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n{canHeaders}\n{canResource}";
var auth = CreateAuthString(blobStorageAccount, signStr, storageKey);
var urlPath = $"https://{blobStorageAccount}.blob.core.windows.net/{containerName}/{blobName}";
Uri uri = new Uri(urlPath);
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-date", dt);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-version", msVersion);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-client-request-id", clientRequestId);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", auth);
HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
var status =  response.IsSuccessStatusCode;


private static string CreateAuthString(string blobStorageAccount,string signStr,string blobStorageAccessKey)
{
   var signature = string.Empty;
   byte[] unicodeKey = Convert.FromBase64String(blobStorageAccessKey);
   using (HMACSHA256 hmacSha256 = new HMACSHA256(unicodeKey))
   {
      byte[] dataToHmac = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signStr);
      signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmacSha256.ComputeHash(dataToHmac));
   }

     var authorizationHeader = String.Format(
         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
         "{0} {1}:{2}",
         "SharedKey",
         blobStorageAccount,
         signature);

       return authorizationHeader;
  }
```

[image]

Comment: This works, the canonicalizedResource change is what was needed. Can I ask where you got the info from as it does not match the Azure Documentation

Comment: It seems that it is a document issue, according to the [Get blob API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob) https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob, I assume  that canonicalizedResource should be `$"/{blobStorageAccount}/{containerName}/{blobName}"`.